# Script unable to resolve the namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I created two files within a same directory.

`test.php`

```
<?php

namespace one;

class Greet{
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'Hello';
    }
}

namespace two;

class Fruit{
    public function __construct(){
        echo 'Orange';
    }
}
```

and `tester.php`:

```
<?php

 error_reporting('-1');
 use one\Greet;
 $object = new Greet();
```

When I run `tester.php` I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'one\Greet' not found in C:\wamp\www\tester.php on line 5
```

What could be the reason for it? I did specify the namespace that I want to use.

Comment: Include class file `test.php`. PHP will not do it for you unless you define an autoloader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include `test.php` file in your `tester.php`.

Writing `use one\Greet;` doesn't means that `test.php` will be included.
You either have to include it by yourself with `require` or `include` construct:

```
error_reporting('-1');
include 'test.php';

use one\Greet;
$object = new Greet();
```

Or register an autoloader function, which will automatically try to load classes according to some logics, still defined by you. More about [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

And finally - defining several namespaces in one file is **not recommended**.